# Why can't I create this unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class Listener with two child classes, TCP and Domain. I'm trying to create a unique_ptr that will hold an instance of either TCP or Domain, depending on business logic. For some reason I can't understand, this results in an error: `cannot initialize a parameter of type xxx::Listener *with an rvalue of type xxx::Domain *`

Here's my code:

```
unique_ptr<Listener> Listener::create(const Parameters& parameters) {
      unique_ptr<Listener> listener;
      if (parameters.socket.empty()) {
        listener.reset(new TCP(parameters));
      } else {
        listener.reset(new Domain(parameters));
      }
      return listener;
    }
```

**Update**

Domain and TCP are indeed children of Listener. No other classes with the same name in the project. Is there anything else I can do to debug this further?

Comment: Are you 100% sure `Domain` is a child class of `Listener`?

Comment: "is there anything else I can do to debug this further" 1/ Create an MVCE, 2/ Look more closely at the error messages, and failing that 3/ post 1 and 2. If you look at the second MVCE in my answer, it's clear that the error you are getting is the compiler explicitly telling you that "xxx::Domain" is *not* publicly derived from "xxx::Listener".

Comment: This is why you are supposed to post **a testcase**. After over _six years_ on SO you should know that by now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I meant to ask if there's a compiler flag I should pass to make this work. Because the code compiles just fine although my IDE doesn't like it (and the executable crashes).

Comment: @ruipacheco: We don't know what "this" is yet, because you have failed to present a MCVE/testcase.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly qualifying `Domain` with it's namespace? Are you `using` namespaces in your code or is `unique_ptr` achieved by `using std::unique_ptr`? (see http://ideone.com/XUs0na). A namespace conflict if you are `using` would explain the problem, and your certainty the names are correct would be explained by your trusting the IDE which is a mistake when you're `using`.

Comment: Your question says it's an error. Is it an error or an IntelliSense warning and a crash you *think* is related but haven't debugged? Ambiguity is not helping you or us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an MVCE that suggests the problem is that the classes aren't related the way you think, or that `Domain` and `TCP` are not resolving to what you think at this location in the code.

```
#include <memory>

struct A {};
struct B : public A {};
struct C : public A {};
struct D : public C {};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<A> ptr;
    ptr.reset(new B);
    ptr.reset(new C);
    ptr.reset(new D);
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/2qhIqC

And a demonstration of failure, note that "Branch" is fine but DIAMOND gives an "ambiguous" error:

```
#include <memory>

struct Listener {};
struct TCP : public Listener {};
struct Domain : public Listener {};
struct A {};
struct Branch : public TCP, public A {};
struct DIAMOND : public TCP, public Domain {};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Listener> ptr;
    ptr.reset(new TCP);
    ptr.reset(new Domain);
    ptr.reset(new Branch);
    ptr.reset(new DIAMOND);
}
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/prjXeL

Comment: This could be it, actually. Listener in my case Listener inherits from a parent class. Why would this be a problem?

Comment: What does the inheritance hierarchy look like?

Answer (score 1):

[`std::unique_ptr::reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) takes a *pointer* to the template arg of `Listener`, so domain must be derived from `Listener`.